# How to handle uncaught expception in proxy/registry service in node js?

Tags: node.js, microservices, api-gateway, uncaught-exception

We have multiple microservice projects and one proxy/service registry which all services apis register in this service. now we want to catch uncaught expections. Since all services share registry service, we were thinking maybe this could be done in there, since all services register at startup. Is it possible to catch in the registry service if yes how can we ? I am thinking when we are forwarding apis from registry service to another service can we catch in there?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Do you want to kill deployment in case of false registration please describe the use case and not the solution you think suitable for you